# TCPDF ajustar el alto según el contenido

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

tengo una duda.
Estoy creando un pdf con la libreria de TCPDF la cual me genera un ticket dependiendo los datos que tengo en mi api, el problema es que por ejemplo si se agrega en el punto de venta varios productos y servicios no se ajusta el tamaño del pdf al contenido.

[image: Codigo del controlador]

la parte de $medidas es para darle un ancho y un alto, esto me sirve para los comprobantes de pago ya que no varian en las dimensiones del contenido, el problema es cuando imprimo el ticket de los productos vendidos, si le doy una medida especifica me lo corta y le deja un espacio antes de que se imprima la otra parte.

Ahor mi duda, ¡Hay forma que en lugar de ponerle el alto se pueda generar dependiendo del contenido del html que uso?

Agradezco su atención y tiempo.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código en lugar de usar screenshots. Te sugiero hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas la comunidad y cómo participar.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].